# New content not visible because browser cache

Tags: html

I have updated my website with some new content.
I talked to some people to view the content on their computers, 
but it seems like they cant's see the content unless they delete their browser cache. Is there a way to handle this by my side, so all new things show up automatically on every browser?

Comment: Use this metatags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576721/how-to-clear-browsers-cache-from-server-side

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to accomplish this without cleaning the cache.**

Although, you can delete cache easily by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+R` (atleast on firefox).

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot erase a remove user's browser cache from Server/Client-side code.**

Going forward, best you could do is tell the browsers `not to cache at all` in future, or `to cache for a specified time` (less than next expected update)

```
Cache-Control : no-cache

Cache-Control : max-age=315600
```

[**ETag**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en#validating-cached-responses-with-etags) sounds like it could serve the purpose (though I've never used).

> The server generates and returns an arbitrary token which is typically
>   a hash or some other fingerprint of the contents of the file. The
>   client does not need to know how the fingerprint is generated, it only
>   needs to send it to the server on the next request: if the fingerprint
>   is still the same then the resource has not changed and we can skip
>   the download.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot remote-wipe someone's cache. This time your only options are to wait, or tell your users to clear their cache, or instruct them to vigorously press refresh a few times, which will cause most browsers to refresh the page.
2. For future reference, there are two types of caching: expiration based caches and ETag caches.

   If you set an explicit expiration date on your HTTP response, the client will not check back at all until that expiration date has passed. This greatly reduces network traffic, at the tradeoff of possibly having outdated content out there. Choose your expiration dates wisely for the best tradeoff.

   The alternative is ETags, in which case the server sends an ETag token, and the client will inquire with "send me new content unless this token is still valid". This only reduces network traffic somewhat, but you're guaranteed to always have the latest content out there.

   You need to balance your caching strategy in practice. First decide if you need caching at all, then decide how much you need and what tradeoff you're willing to make. For a high-traffic site even a cache of a few minutes can be worthwhile, while the issue of outdated content will be minuscule in this scenario.